# Typescript Type Definition References

Tags: visual-studio, knockout.js

I have a project with multiple typescript files.
If I add a new typescript file I have to reference typings in order to compile it, VS couldn't resolve them itself. Also I have empty .ts file that doesn't require referencing typings, so I put code into it and it works.

When I found out it I kept the file and now when I need to create new .ts file, I copy that file and everything works like a charm.

So suppose in a folder I have two .ts files side by side: a copy of a magic file and a newly created one.

If I put this code in the magic file

```
class Test {
    test: KnockoutObservable<string>;
}
```

it compiles. If I put the same code into another file it says

> Cannot find name KnockoutObservable

What is so special about the first file?

I'm using Visual Studio 2015.
I have installed Knockout typings.
I have empty tsconfig.json file in the solution.
I don't want to reference typings using /// reference comment.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [TSD](http://definitelytyped.org/tsd/) and install appropriate ".d.ts" file, e.g. for knockout:

```
tsd install knockout
```

It downloads "knockout.d.ts" into your project and places definition into typings folder:

```
typings/knockout/knockout.d.ts
```

Then you can add corresponding reference to the top or your "ts" file. e.g.:

```
/// <reference path="../../typings/knockout/knockout.d.ts" />
```